# integration of iCloud in Android device

Tags: android, icloud, icloud-api

I have checked out other links about icloud but all of them say that it is only for Iphones not for android developers but all the posts are of as old as of of near about july 2012

so can anyone please tell me is there any iCloud api or a procedure to implement icloud for android developers

I have also found some link where they have mentioned that iCloud is now renamed as Cloudme and there are apis in android market too

so if anyone can give a link or show a procedure to implement that code for android

it will be really helpful
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Apple does not provide any iCloud APIs for Android, only for iOS devices and Macs. It's not an open system where third parties can create their own APIs. I don't know what "Cloudme" is, but it's not iCloud.